# Binding checkbox with observablecollection

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid with a column i would like to fill with data.
therefore i've made a template selector

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Value" IsReadOnly="False">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
                <c:checkBoxCheckConverter 
                        ValueIsBoolean="{StaticResource ValueIsBoolean}"
                        ValueIsColumn3="{StaticResource ValueIsColumn3}"/>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplateSelector>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Template :

```
 public class checkBoxCheckConverter : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate ValueIsBoolean
    { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate ValueIsColumn3
    { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {

        cDGStructure cdgStructure = item as cDGStructure;
        if (cdgStructure != null)
        {
            if (((cdgStructure.Column3) == "True") | ((cdgStructure.Column3) == "False"))
                return ValueIsBoolean;
            else
                // return ValueIsNotBoolean;
                cdgStructure = cdgStructure;
            return ValueIsColumn3;

        }
        else
            return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}


 <DataTemplate x:Key="ValueIsBoolean">
        <CheckBox Content="">
            <CheckBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="False"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Column3, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </CheckBox.Style>
        </CheckBox>
     </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ValueIsColumn3">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Column3, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The Data structure used :

```
public class cDGStructure : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _column1; //name
    private string _column2; //type
    private string _column3; //value
    private string _column4; //comment          
    //comment

    public cDGStructure(string column1, string column2, string column3, string column4)
    {
        _column1 = column1;
        _column2 = column2;
        _column3 = column3;
        _column4 = column4;
    }

    public string Column1
    {
        get { return _column1; }
        set
        {
            _column1 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Column1");

        }
    }

    public string Column2
    {
        get { return _column2; }
        set
        {
            _column2 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Column2");
        }
    }

    public string Column3
    {
        get { return _column3; }
        set
        {
            _column3 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Column3");
        }
    }

    public string Column4
    {
        get { return _column4; }
        set
        {
            _column4 = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Column4");
        }
    }

#region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion

    #region Private Helpers
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

The grid is filled like :

```
public ObservableCollection<cDGStructure> collSymbolsDataGrid = new ObservableCollection<cDGStructure>();

        moi =  "moi"; 
        waar = "True"; 
        nwaar = "False";

        collSymbolsDataGrid.Add(new cDGStructure(moi, moi, nwaar, moi));
        collSymbolsDataGrid.Add(new cDGStructure(moi, moi, waar, moi));
        collSymbolsDataGrid.Add(new cDGStructure(moi, moi, moi, moi));
        InitializeComponent();
        dgSymbolGrid.ItemsSource = collSymbolsDataGrid;
```

The Datagrid is filled with the correct objects and correct data. 
The textbox is correctly binded, the program notifies the changes made in runtime after lost focus.

Now the problem is the checkbox. By Initialization the datagrid shows the correct data only my observablecollection doesn't see any changes made during runtime (IsChecked property). I need to have my collection up to date.

What is the best way to implement this ? 
I tried to implement a boolean converter but no succes:( 
who can help me ?

Comment: Why dont you use the datatype ``boolean`` for your true/false values instead of strings? You would need to have a converter in your Binding for it to work, since something needs to convert your string into boolean, no one is doing that for you. But if you changed the datatype it would work.

Comment: i use the structure in multiple classes also for sql queries etc. So i would like to keep the structure as it is now.

Comment: Had a closer look at what you are doing there and I must say "interessting". :) I would recommend instead of your datatrigger thing in your ``ValueIsBoolean`` DataTemplate, go and make an other member in your ``cDGStructure`` that is of type ``boolean`` than in the setter of your column properties do your logic of "is my string a boolean" and if that is the case set the value accordingly at that newly created member, and than bind your Checkbox to that member.

Comment: I believe you dont see any changes done to your object is 'cause you are just never listening to the ``IsChecked`` property of your Checkbox you only have a trigger on your ``Column3`` member. You are simply missing the part "IsChecked changed".

Comment: If my comment isnt clear, tell me and I will try to invest time for an answer.

Comment: i think i do understand i will try to implement today, after that i will come back with the result :)

Comment: @Godjan *"only my observablecollection doesn't see any changes"* -- ObservableCollection never listens to anything for changes. Its job is to raise the `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` event when somebody adds, removes, or replaces one or more of its items. That's the only thing it does that has anything to do with notifications. You also have "Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged" on a binding where it can't possibly make any difference. This stuff is a lot easier to deal with if you learn it, instead of doing stuff at random and guessing.

Comment: @EdPlunkett i know that the checkbox doesn't make any changes in my collection that is the whole problem, i don't know what te correct method is to bind the data. It is obvious that IsChecked  (boolean ) can not bind with string without a conversion.

Comment: Actually it's not at all obvious that CheckBox.IsChecked can't bind to a string property without a conversion. I just tested it and it works fine. It sets the property to "True" or "False", and is set correctly on startup when the property is initialized to "True". WPF makes lavish use of type converters without being asked to.

Comment: I think the problem is more along the line of `TemplateSelector` not being re-evaluated on inner property changes, no matter the report mechanism. It only evaluates when the whole data object changes.

Comment: What's not clear to me, @Godjan, is exactly what's failing here. It's pretty clear the template selector isn't working; are the templates themselves working?

Comment: The templates are working fine. so my column in data grid looks like :
row 1  :  Checkbox ( ischecked False) 
row 2 :  Checkbox ( ischecked True) 
row 3 :  TextBox ( "moi" )

Comment: Your checkbox template content could be just this: `<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Column3}" />`.

Comment: But so it seems the problem is this: `Column3` changes from "True" to "Albacore", and the template doesn't change. That's because there's nothing there to inform anything in the XAML that the template selector needs to be reinvoked when `Column3` gets a new value. Your templates have bindings with `"Column3"` in their `Path` property, so those bindings are listening to the parent object of `Column3` for a `PropertyChanged` event for "Column3". No such arrangements have been made with the template selector.

Comment: Furthermore, no such arrangements *can* be made with it, because a DataTemplateSelector is not a subclass of `DependencyObject`, hence you can't put a binding on any of its properties. The DataGridTemplateColumn will reinvoke it when the DataGridTemplateColumn's DataContext is replaced with a new object, but that never happens.

Comment: In grek40's excellent answer, `Binding="{Binding Column3}"` in the DataTriggers fills in the piece you were missing.

Comment: I have solved the "problem" with the following instruction: "<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Column3, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />"

Thanks for the quick support @EdPlunkett and Rand Random

Comment: @Godjan Please remove `Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` from that binding. You will find that it works exactly the same without them, because that property *already* binds two way by default, and it already updates the source when the property changes. You can spend hours adding random intellisense suggestions that you don't understand, without ever making a single change in your code that could have the slightest hope of fixing anything. It's not a productive use of your time, though it does serve as a warning to people reading your question.

Answer (score 2):

The TemplateSelector is not a suitable tool to change on an objects dynamically changing property values. It is meant to select on things like the object type or non-changing property values.

For dynamic changes on property, use style triggers instead. Something similar to the following:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <!-- Template or ContentTemplate? -->
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ValueIsColumn3}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!-- Alternative: use an IsBoolean converter instead of testing True and False separately -->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Column3}" Value="True">
                    <!-- Template or ContentTemplate? -->
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ValueIsBoolean}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Column3}" Value="False">
                    <!-- Template or ContentTemplate? -->
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ValueIsBoolean}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```